# Route Priority for same routes in AWS Route table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering, aws-direct-connect

Setup:
Single AWS account, with environments in us-east-1, and ca-central-1.

The VPCs in each region are connected using a VPC-peering, and another physical link via DirectConnect. The prefixes are appearing as:

```
172.1.0.0/16 via pcx-* (VPC peering route)
172.1.0.0/16 via vgw-* (VGW/DirectConnect route via Propagation)
```

However, the traffic is using only the VPC-peering route.

How do we get it to use the VGW/DX route and fallback to VPC peering when the path via VGW/DX is not available?

Comment: Not sure, but I wonder if this requires [Transit Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/how-transit-gateways-work.html).